# Sorting order of files

Tags: powershell

I have an application that restores latest database backup every night. So it happened that the backup file was not uploaded to the backup folder and the application picked a folder (which has latest changes) instead of a backup file.

```
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
```

I want is a latest backup file to be picked irregardless of of the date. I need this app to be able to locate only latest file with extension of `.bak` only.

Comment: `get-childitem -path $dir -filter *.bak`

Comment: Remove the `-Descending` switch if you want the *latest*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there - just filter by file extension and get first result from the list:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -filter *.bak| Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending)[0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much gents, all the answers mentioned are working!!

Comment: @Immortal If this answer solved your problem, consider clicking the checkmark on the left to mark it "accepted"